# How to get logs of last hour in linux using awk command

Tags: linux, awk

I have a logs file named source.log having time format like :-

```
Fri, 09 Dec 2016 05:03:29 GMT 127.0.0.1
```

and i am using script to get logs from a logs file for last 1 hour.

Script:-

```
awk -vDate=`date -d'now-1 hour' +[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S` '$4 > Date {print Date, $0}' source.log > target.log
```

But this script gives the result same as like the source file.
There is something wrong in time format matching, due to which it is not giving last hour records.

Comment: $4 for the data you show is 2016. What did you think it would be?

Comment: $4 would be the number of columns for data to show.

I am trying to write a script to collect the last 1 hour logs from app log files. My script is collecting all the logs from the log file and I need only last 1 hour logs. 

**Example of app log file:-**

Wed, 07 Dec 2016 06:44:35 GMT connect deprecated methodOverride: use method-override

Comment: Well, I suggest you change your print to show you Date and $4. You'd better "bound" them with something, else you'll still think different. Even if what you thought were true, how would "number of columns for data to show" being greater than what you have established in Date help you in way?

Comment: You look at using `find` for this, i.e. - `$ find logs_dir -mmin -60` will show files modified in the last hour.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to help the OP, but maybe this answer can help anyone else in this situation.

First it's necessary to compare the whole date and not only the time part, because times near midnight.

Note that `awk` can only compare strings and numbers. Some awk implementations have the `mktime()` function that converts a specifically formatted string into [UNIX timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), in order to make datetime comparisons, but it doesn't support any datetime format, so we can't use it.

The best way would be changing (if possible) the datetime format of the log entries, using `'YYMMDDhhmmss'` datetime format or [ISO format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). In this way, comparing  two datetimes is simple as compare strings or numbers.

But let's assume that we can't change log entries date format, so we'll need to convert ourselves inside `awk`:

```
awk -vDate="`date -d'now-1 hour' +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`" '
    BEGIN{
        for(i=0; i<12; i++)
            MON[substr("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", i*3+1, 3)] = sprintf("%02d", i+1);
    }
    toDate() > Date
    function toDate(){
        time = $5; gsub(/:/, "", time);
        return $4 MON[$3] $2 time;
    }' source.log
```

**Explanation**

- `-vDate=...` sets the `Date` awk variable with the initial datetime (one hour ago).
- `BEGIN` section creates an array indexed by the month abbreviation (it's especific to english)
- `toDate()` function converts the line's fields into a string with the same format as `Date` variable (`YYYMMDDhhmmss`).
- Finally when the condition `toDate() > Date` is true, awk prints the current line (log entry).